# Python: Justifying Columns of Nested Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, justify

What I want to do is to make a justified column from a nested array as the title states. However I just can't figure out how to pull it off. So this is the array..

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

This is what I want to achieve(notice the alignment):

```
  apples Alice  dogs
 oranges   Bob  cats
cherries Carol moose
  banana David goose
```

I was able to create code to successfully justify each of the sub-arrays but my result is simply vertical. Mainly because I haven't figured out code to make it into rows and columns so I have just a long single column. My result looks like:

```
  apples
 oranges
cherries
  banana
Alice
  Bob
Carol
...#you get the picture
```

EDIT:
So my question is simply how I would break it into 3 different columns assuming you didn't already know the metadata of the array e.g(number of of sub-arrays)

In case you'd want to see my source code it's here...

```
#function to get the longest word in the sub-array
#to determine justification length
def maxLength(someList):
    count = {}
    max_num = 0
    for item in someList:
        count[item] = len(item)
    for value in count.values():
        if value > max_num:
            max_num = value
    return(max_num)

#function to store the length of the longest words 
#of each sub-array into an array
def maxWidths(tableData):
    widths = []
    for i in range(len(tableData)):
        widths.insert(i,maxLength(tableData[i]))
    return(widths)

#function to print table(this is the part that needs work)                      
def printTable(tableData):
    widths = maxWidths(tableData)
    for i in range(len(tableData)):
        for item in tableData[i]:
            print(item.rjust(widths[i]))
```

I just included my code in order to help but I'm sure some people out there can do it in less than 10 lines magically. I would really love to see that kind of answer(that's the kind I'll accept as the correct one) but please explain any weird syntax. But if you just want to add to my already existing work that would be great as well and easier for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. They both work perfectly I'm only posting this answer because I wanted to merge parts of the efforts of both into one.

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

#function to get an array of the length of the longest words
def Widths(tableData):
    widths = [len(max(column, key=len)) for column in tableData]
    return(widths)

#function to print table                      
def printTable(tableData):
    widths = Widths(tableData)
    for i in range(len(tableData[0])):
        for j in range(len(tableData)):
            try:
                print(tableData[j][i].rjust(widths[j]), end = ' ')
            except:
                pass
        print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the sublists so you'll get triplets of values. Then you can format the values into columns of width 8, 5, 5, right justified, padded with spaces (see [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align)):

```
for fruit, person, animal in zip(*tableData):
   print('{: >8} {: >5} {: >5}'.format(fruit, person, animal))
```

For a more general answer, you can get the max width of each column, and create a format string for each width:

```
widths = [max(len(value) for value in column) for column in tableData]
line = ' '.join('{{: >{width}}}'.format(width=width)
                for width in widths)
for row in zip(*tableData):
    print(line.format(*row))
```

Comment: Wow...that's some syntax I'm not at all familiar with, but let's assume that you didn't know the number of sub-arrays or data types in the array. How would you handle it?

Comment: That would be a different question for the whole of Stack Overflow to consider.

Comment: If you look at my source code you'll notice I never directly made use of the metadata of the array. Hence the numerous functions..

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to assign to the line variable though. That line also raised an IndexError when I tried running it

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't escaped the curly braces

Answer (score 0):

I edited it according to your EDIT. You can do this to stick with the basics:

```
from __future__ import print_function

tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
max_width=[]
for i in tableData:
    width=[]
    for obj in range(0,len(i)):
        width.append(len(i[obj])) #adds the len(i[obj])
    max_width.append(max(width)) #appends the length of longest str of the column

max_height = max(len(i) for i in tableData) #Finds the max height of the array

for obj in range(0,max_height): #obj is the number of item in a row
    for index, i in enumerate(tableData): #i a single column in tableData
        try: #Just in case if one of the rows has fewer item than the rest
            print ("{0:>{1}}".format(i[obj], max_width[index]+1), end="") #prints it with the proper formatting
        except:
            pass
    print("")
```

Comment: This definitely gets the job done, although you should change range(0,4) as it's metadata from the table. Could you add comments to help me keep track of how the program accomplished the task

Comment: @ITJ Sorry if the comments is confusing and I changed range(0,4) to support different tables. Hope it helped